# how to convert hexadecimal to int

Tags: c#

First I receive the data and convert it to string.

```
data = client.Receive(ref ep);
string received = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```

The string I get is **FF-FF-FF-FF-66-0A**.
And I try to get INT values from it.

```
foreach (var item in received)
{
    int rec = Convert.ToInt32(item);
    int rec = Convert.ToInt32(item,16); 

    //IF I try second line I get error
    //cannot convert from 'int' to 'system.iformatprovider' 
}
```

From using that first line **int rec = Convert.ToInt32(item);**  I get numbers like this **70
70
70
70
45
45
70
70
70
70**

As I figured it out I'm converting F > 70 and F > 70, but how to convert FF and make it work by getting FF > 255

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be doing `BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0)`?

Comment: Just tried doing so, my data I get becomes -1. And the data I get before is good

Comment: Well an `int` is 32 bits, but that hex number you have is 48 bits. Do you just want to ignore the extra bits at the end?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think he only wants the single numbers, not one long number.

Comment: @Master117 Ah right - I wonder why he wants bytes stored as ints rather than just bytes...

Comment: I need to convert them to get IP address'es

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here you go

```
string input = "FF-FF-FF-FF-66-0A";
int[] result = input.Split('-').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x, 16)).ToArray();
```

Comment: if I could ask one more question. FF-FF-FF-FF - that's is IP address, 66-0A - that is Port. So is it possible to connect 66 and 0A before converting them? Now I have made so after FF it adds .(dot) and increase count by 1 so I would no when it reaches port. But how to combine them.

Comment: sure with `string ip_port = string.Join("-", ip, port);`

Answer (score 1):

Use ToInt32(x,16);

```
string[] hexValuesSplit = received.Split('-');
foreach (String hex in hexValuesSplit)
{
  // Convert the number expressed in base-16 to an integer.
  int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
  Console.WriteLine("hexadecimal value = {0}, int value = {1}",
                    hex, value);
}
```

[MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach you might want to try.

Since you say that you're parsing IP addresses, you could do something like this:

```
string x = "FF-FF-FF-FF-66-0A";
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(x.Replace("-", ":") + ":0:0");
```

Note that you are using IPv6 with the last two values 0 (I think), so I had to add ":0:0" to the end of the string before parsing it.

(Note: It's not clear what IP scheme you are actually using, but it seems to me that there should be some way for you to use the `IPAddress` class to parse them.)

Comment: I am getting them from master server, and I get them as hexadecimals

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    int intNumber = int.Parse("FF",system.Globalization.NumberStyle.HexNumber);